# Android Fragment Persist Listeners on Configuration Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I want to doublecheck the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621614/1114105) is the best one for persisting listeners throughout normal fragments

I have an Activity that implements a bunch of listener Interfaces and creates an instance of `QuestionsFragment` which in turn creates many instances of `QuestionFragment`.

Both `QuestionsFragment` and `QuestionFragment` have a `newInstance()` function that takes in these listeners. My Activity calls `QuestionsFragment.newInstance()` when the user presses a button. `QuestionsFragment` `onViewCreated()` function in turn calls `QuestionFragment.newInstance()` and passes along some of these listeners.

Here is the code for `QuestionsFragment.newInstance()`.

```
 fun newInstance(
            config: QuestionsConfig,
            onCompleteListener: OnCompleteListener,
            onDismissListener: OnDismissListener,
            customInputHandler: QuestionFragment.CustomInputHandler? = null,
            onSubmitListener: OnSubmitListener? = null,
            onPageChangeListener: ((Int) -> Unit)? = null,
            onErrorListener: QuestionFragment.OnErrorListener? = null
        ): QuestionsFragment {
            return QuestionsFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putParcelable(ARG_QUESTIONS_CONFIG, config)

                }
                this.onPageCompleteListener = onPageChangeListener
                this.onCompleteListener = onCompleteListener
                this.onSubmitListener = onSubmitListener
                this.onDismissListener = onDismissListener
                this.customInputHandler = customInputHandler // Is this still needed?
                this.onErrorListener = onErrorListener
            }
        }
```

Here is the one for `QuestionFragment.newInstance()`

```
fun newInstance(
            question: Question,
            onSubmitListener: OnSubmitListener,
            customInputHandler: CustomInputHandler? = null,
            onErrorListener: OnErrorListener? = null
        ) = QuestionFragment()
            .apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putParcelable(ARG_QUESTION, question)
                }
                this.onSubmitListener = onSubmitListener
                this.customInputHandler = customInputHandler
                this.onErrorListener = onErrorListener
            }
```

Thinking of adding something like below to both `QuestionsFragment` and `QuestionFragment` per the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621614/1114105) approach to handle configuration changes

```
 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if(this.customInputHandler == null && context is QuestionFragment.CustomInputHandler){
            this.customInputHandler = context
        }
        // TODO Other if  blocks similar to the one above - one for each listener
    }
  override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        this.customInputHandler = null
        // TODO Other if  blocks similar to the one above - one for each listener
    }
```

If there is a better / more accepted way to do persist listeners on configuration changes would love to learn. There will be quite a few onAttach overrides needed and it feels a bit janky. If this is the best way, is it safe to remove the null check in `onAttached` and also remove the assignments in `newInstance()` to consolidate the listener assignments?

Comment: Have you read the [guide on communicating between fragments and your activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)? None of the APIs run into these problems (which is why they are the recommended solutions).

Comment: Yes, understood that refactoring this to use ViewModel/LiveData is the way to go. As a short-term stop gap though - is the onAttach approach ok or is there some glaring problem where we should definitely not use it?